# "Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin kapsel-plugin-i18n. Please try adding it again." when I'm trying to install kapsel-plugin-i18n for iOS 15 (local)

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, plugins, ios15

Do you know which version of kapsel-plugin-i18n might work with iOS 15 ?

Which version of npm and node might fit with Cordova 9.0.0 ?

Indeed, I had to upgrade the Kapsel plugins for my application to fit with iOS 15 but there is an error when I try to install the kapsel-plugin-i18n. (which comes from the SDK 3.2 SP04 PL1).

"Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin kapsel-plugin-i18n. Please try adding it again."

But the plugin.xml is here, in the local directory.

For information, I'm using :

- Cordova 9.0.0
- npm 6.14.15
- node : 14.18.0
- Mac OS Big Sur (11.6)

The command line I'm using is :
sudo cordova plugin add kapsel-plugin-i18n --searchpath /Absolute path to plugin local directory/.

Thank you for your answer.

Kat

Answer (score 0):

As per the git repo :

> Security holding package
> This package contained malicious code and was
> removed from the registry by the npm security team. A placeholder was
> published to ensure users are not affected in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the answer !
But my plugin is from a local directory and I downloaded the kapsel plugins from the SAP portal.
I am sorry but I don't understand why I've got this error.
Do you know how can I do to have a proper "kapsel-plugin-i18n" which fits with Cordova 9.0.0 and the information above ?
Same question for kapsel-plugin-logger and kapsel-plugin-xhook ?

Thanks !